# Android : Sqlite Database insert?

Tags: android, sqlite

How to insert a string array values to a table?

```
1,1,null,null,9876543210,null,1,-1,3,null,null,Testing message,null,0,0,0
```

The above is the value in a `String[]`. I want to insert this to my database table.

Here's my code : -

```
while((st = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
try
{
    splitArray = st.split("\\n+");
}catch(PatternSyntaxException e ) { }

for(String result_array : splitArray)
{
Toast.makeText(context, result_array, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

What's the SQL statement to do this?

Comment: You can use INSERT statement with for loop.It may help you.

Comment: whats exactly your problem where u stuck? ask in brief

Comment: @Sam_k : I want to insert this string[] to /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db 's sms table. How can i done that?

Comment: Give permission in Manifest file to write sms

Comment: @Sam_k : Yes, i already give that permission and am using insert the sms by this method here (http://pastebin.com/QThYEHSF). How can i insert this string[] to their database by accurate.

Comment: so whats excat error? see in log any exception??

Comment: I don't have a method to do this. Then, how can i get the exception. Which method will i use to insert this?

Comment: @SPK post your code please i will check and tell you where the code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4686/discussion-between-spk-and-sam-k)

Comment: its wrong code where is string array

Comment: @SPK where your sms code yar.. what you want exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have been trying to do the same thing and just worked it out.  you 
want to do something similar to this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

Code

```
 public static final String ADDRESS = "address"; 
 public static final String PERSON = "person"; 
 public static final String DATE = "date"; 
 public static final String READ = "read"; 
 public static final String STATUS = "status"; 
 public static final String TYPE = "type"; 
 public static final String BODY = "body"; 
 public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX = 1; 
 public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT = 2; 
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
 values.put(SMSHelper.ADDRESS, "+61408219690"); 
 values.put(SMSHelper.DATE, "1237080365055"); 
 values.put(SMSHelper.READ, 1); 
 values.put(SMSHelper.STATUS, -1); 
 values.put(SMSHelper.TYPE, 2); 
 values.put(SMSHelper.BODY, "SMS inserting test"); 
 Uri inserted = getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content:// sms"), values);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table with one column of type 'TEXT' and all you wish is to enter 
those string but in one commit: then as far as I know you have to make an INSERT statement
for each of them, there is no way to insert all the string in only 1 INSERT statement (as long as you want each string to be a row in the table)

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database)